# Bug using Python 3.7 (from QGIS) and trying to install package with pip

Tags: qgis-3, windows, python-3, pip

I use QGIS 3.6 and Python 3.7 and I try to install a package with pip in command line tool under Windows 7 but I have the following message :

```
Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: unable to load the file system codec
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x0000188c (most recent call first):
```

My path and PYTHONPATH are well configured with link to QGIS' Python folders. The problem appeared recently with use of Python 3.7.

Answer (score 4):

If you use OSGeo4W try:

1. In OSGeo4W installer: `install python3-pip`
2. In OSGeo4W shell: `call C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\py3_env.bat`
3. In OSGeo4W shell: `pip3 install desired-package-name`

Comment: Thanks, worked for me, but only after running OSGeo4W shell as administrator.

Answer (score 2):

I installed QGIS 3.2 back with Python 3.6 without changing anything else (except the paths of Windows) and I can now use `pip install`. I think the problem certainly comes from Python 3.7.